# Subformula numbering problem in ConTeXt

Tags: math-mode, context

The second formula has **no number**. Is it a bug?

```
\starttext

\startsubformulas[eq:equation]

\placeformula[eq:first]
\startformula
    c^2 = a^2 + b^2
\stopformula

\placeformula[eq:second]
\startformula
    c^2 = a^2 + b^2
\stopformula

\stopsubformulas

\stoptext
```